# SQL Query for mass deleting for no primary key table

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I have a SQL Table that doesn't have a primary key but should have which is the account_id, key and index.

But unfortunately, I already have millions of entries before I was able to notice this problem.

I have account_id from 2000001 and upto around 2004000+ and also several keys which should've been primary keys so that only the value would be replaced if ever there is an update.

Sample image below,
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BG4tT.png

There should only be 1 #betaminutes and #online_minute under account_id 2000846 and the value should only be the highest

Is it possible to do a mass delete on each and every account_id for all the different keys I have and only save the entry with the highest value for each account_id's keys?

Thank you

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A large delete will be expensive, you are using.  In MySQL, you can use:

```
delete t
    from t join
         (select account_id, key, max(value) as max_value
          from t
          group by account_id, key
          having count(*) > 1
         ) tt
         using (account_id, key)
     where value < max_value;
```

Note:  If there are ties for the highest value, then this will keep the ties, but your sample data suggests that there are no ties.

Comment: So from the following code

`delete t
    from t join
         (select account_id, #betaminutes, max(value) as max_value
          from t
          group by account_id, #betaminutes
          having count(*) > 1
         ) tt
         using (account_id, #betaminutes)
     where value < max_value;
`

It will delete all of each account_id's #betaminutes except for the highest value correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `exists` as follows:

```
delete from your_table t
 where exists 
       (select 1 from your_Table tt
         where t.account_id = tt.account_id
           and t.key = tt.key
           and tt.value > t.value)
   -- use following condition if there is more than given key and you only want this query to operat on this two keys
   and t.key in ('#betaminutes', '#online_minute')
```

Comment: So if I use this the following code,

`delete from acc_reg_num_db t
 where exists 
       (select 1 from acc_reg_num_db tt
         where t.account_id = tt.account_id
           and t.key = tt.key
           and tt.value > t.value)
   -- use following condition if there is more than given key and you only want this query to operate on this two keys
   and t.key in ('#betaminutes', '#online_minute') `

This will delete all existing #betaminutes and #online_minute from all of the account_ids and will only save the one with the highest value correct?

Comment: Yes, @ChanchanDeGuzman Highest value per account. so for each account you will have single #betaminutes and #online_minute

Comment: Okay noted on this @Popeye , I would also like to add. What if there are duplicate entries? Like for example if there are 2 entries of 2004683 account id with key #betaminutes at value 10? Will the other 1 get deleted?

Comment: I got an error

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 't
where exists
       (select 1 from acc_reg_num_db tt
         where t.acco' at line 1